# SQL Server: Get All views from All databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Actually I am able to get a list of all databases that contains a certain table:

```
SELECT name
FROM   sys.databases
WHERE  CASE
         WHEN state_desc = 'ONLINE' 
              THEN OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(name) + '.[dbo].[TABLE_NAME]', 'U')
       END IS NOT NULL
```

But now I want to do something similar with the views, in order to list all the views from the database.

Can you help me with this approach?

Regards.

Comment: To list all views try using [sys.viws](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/10/29/sql-server-list-of-all-the-views-from-database/).

Comment: That sort does what i want but only for the current database that im querying, i want the list of all views for each database.

Answer (score 7):

```
CREATE TABLE #v(d SYSNAME, v NVARCHAR(512));

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @sql = N'';

SELECT @sql = @sql + N'INSERT #v(d,v) 
  SELECT ''' + REPLACE(name, '''','''''') + ''',
  QUOTENAME(s.name) + ''.'' + QUOTENAME(v.name)
   FROM ' + QUOTENAME(name) + '.sys.views AS v
   INNER JOIN ' + QUOTENAME(name) + '.sys.schemas AS s
   ON v.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
   WHERE v.is_ms_shipped = 0;
'
FROM sys.databases
WHERE [state] = 0;

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

SELECT [database] = d, [view] = v FROM #v ORDER BY d,v;

DROP TABLE #v;
```

Comment: That worked excellent, but actually what i want also, is the list of the databases something like: db_name | db_table | View for the result set

Comment: So change `[database]` to `[db_name]` and `[view]` to `[db_table]`?